# Format Numbers to Money in ASP.NET Gridview using SQL Stored Procedure as Source

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a SQL Server stored procedure as source of my gridview when it loads. The query has column that results to numbers (money), I want the numerical outputs to have comma when it loads in gridview. Originally in SQL, The query result has no any formatting, as I have tried to practice putting the formatting in the front-end.

Before, I am able to achieve that by putting a boundfield in the gridview definition, and then put attribute name datafield, giving its value based on the name of the column or alias in  SQL. However in my case this time, the stored procedure column has a dynamic alias, because it is resulting a column with a specific date (it is changing depending on the days of the week).

**Stored procedure goes something like this  (Last part)**

```
 set @query = 'select locationd, Name ' +
        ',(SUM(Day1)) as '+ '[' + @sdateVC1 + ']'  +
        ',(SUM(Day2)) as '+ '[' + @sdateVC2 + ']'  +
        ',(SUM(Day3)) as '+ '[' + @sdateVC3 + ']'  +
        ',(SUM(Day4)) as '+ '[' + @sdateVC4 + ']'  +
        ',(SUM(Day5)) as '+ '[' + @sdateVC5 + ']'  +
        ',(SUM(Day6)) as '+ '[' + @sdateVC6 + ']'  +
        ',(SUM(Day7)) as '+ '[' + @sdateVC7 + ']'  +
        ',(SUM(ISNULL(Day1,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day2,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day3,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day4,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day5,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day6,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day7,0)))as ''TOTAL'' ' +  
        ',RANK() over (partition by locationd order by ((SUM(ISNULL(Day1,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day2,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day3,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day4,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day5,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day6,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day7,0)))) DESC) as ''Ranking'' ' +    
        'from #newestWSR4 ' +
        'group by locationd,  Name ' +
        --'order by locationd, Name ' 
         'union all' +
          ' select ''-'', ''TOTAL'',  sum(day1),  sum(day2),  sum(day3), sum(day4), sum(day5),  sum(day6), sum(day7), (SUM(ISNULL(Day1,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day2,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day3,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day4,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day5,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day6,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Day7,0))), ''-''    ' +
          'from #newestWSR4 '
```

**The gridview code in ASP.net is like this**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdWSR" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"
    GridLines="Vertical" Font-Size="Smaller" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" 
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >

<emptydatarowstyle backcolor="white" forecolor="black"/> 
<emptydatatemplate> No Data Found.</emptydatatemplate> 

 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

  <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField  DataField="locationd" />
     <asp:BoundField  DataField="name"   />
     <asp:BoundField Datafield=""  DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}" />
   </Columns>

   <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="25px"/>
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
 <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**Please take note of this part in the code above**

```
 <asp:BoundField  DataField="locationd" />
 <asp:BoundField  DataField="name"   />
 <asp:BoundField  Datafield="" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}" />
```

As you can see, I've put only three boundfield for testing purposes. In there I don't know what to put in the datafield value since , the alias column in SQL stored procedure is dynamically changing or not fixed, unlike with the first two boundfields (which column names / alias in SQL are fixed)

**Is this case possible to be answered? or should I consider now doing the solution on back-end (SQL) to achieve my desired result?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: set AutogenerateColumns to true in gridview

Comment: Why can't you use an alias in your Stored Procedure to have a fixed name for the field? Can you show us your SP?

Comment: Hi, question is updated, supplied the stored procedure (partly)

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you don't do any formatting thing in sp,
it will overload your system in terms of optimization,

prefer c# instead

```
    DataTable dt=mySP();
    for(i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
    dt.Rows[i][10]=Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][10]).ToString("#,###,###,###,###,##0.00");
    }
    GridView1.DatSource=dt;
```

Comment: So, my preferred answer to just do it on the datafield is not a possible solution? I will try then your sugsestion :)

Comment: I don't use datatable, How can I insert the codes? Sorry.

Comment: for your comment 1 i will say make autogenerate column true and format your text in rowdatabound event by for loop
for second with minor changes you can use datatable,if you are useing object then also you can covert to to datatable by obj.CopyToDataTable
or you can add new property in object with datattype string and doing same written above

Comment: One more question and clarification, I actually have 8 columns to convert to money format. Applying the codes you suggested with looping, do you think it is still more ideal to apply those (with loops) compare to the formatting done in SQL itself, PERFORMANCE WISE? @VISHMAY

Comment: for 8 columns it is great if you use c# for loop as in sql select format or any other function will have to execute 8 times per row, and c# is comparatively faster in such type of task and loop will be executed 1 time only so i prefer c#

Comment: if you still want to do it SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1)

Comment: I already have a working code in SQL (Backend) way of doing it. I am really considering your suggestion but it is not working.

Comment: it is very simple in c#, i m writing code becoz you are not getting working output,   gridView1.DataBind();
for(int i=0;i<gridView1.Rows.Count;i++){
gridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text=Convert.ToDouble( gridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text).ToString("###,###,###,##0.##);
gridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j+1].Text=Convert.ToDouble( gridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j+1].Text).ToString("###,###,###,##0.##);
...
}
here j is column index need not to be changed

Answer (score 0):

try formatting the string like this in your stored procedure:

```
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(SUM(Day1) AS money), 1)
```

or like this -

```
FORMAT(SUM(Day1),'###,###,###')
```

Comment: As much as possible, Ill try not to do it in backend, because I'm getting the total per column, when I do that it can't be summed

Comment: Hi @CoOl I think Format fucntion will work? because it does not convert the number into string, But it is not recognized function because I am only using sql server 2008

Comment: Yeah, it was introduced in SQL Server 2012